# Firebase Functions logging objects takes up a lot of space

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

We have our firebase function `console.log()` an object near the end of the execution.

In the past it always clumped the entire object into one single dropdown in the Firebase Functions Log interface but now it seems to put each key of the object in a separate line making it not only take up more space but quite unreadable.

This seems to happen mostly when objects are stringified like:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'}))
```

Below is an example of an error object being logged:

[image]

How can this madness be put into a single dropdown again?

We are using:

```
"firebase-admin": "^8.6.1",
"firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
```

Thank you!

Comment: great question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an object to log, I recommend just pass it directly to `console.log()`.  `JSON.stringify()` might be adding carriage returns, which could be interpreted as multiple lines to log.

```
console.log({key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'})
```

Just make sure that the object doesn't contain references to other very complex objects (especially self-referential objects), otherwise it could cause problems with evaluating the final string at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I'll rewrite some stuff and see if that fixes it!

Answer (score 1):

Neither console.log(data) nor console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) worked for me.
Using the sdk logger worked for me:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
functions.logger.log(data);
```

As described here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#logger-sdk

Answer (score 0):

If you put

```
require('firebase-functions/lib/logger/compat');
```

at the top of your functions code with the latest version of the sdk
logs should come in 1 single line

src: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/612#issuecomment-646652675